# if-then-else expression works but cond does not in ocaml factorial function

Tags: if-statement, ocaml

```
let cond (a,b,c) =
    match a with
    | true -> b
    | false -> c

let rec fact n =
    cond (n=0,1, n * fact (n-1))

let rec fact n =
    if n=0 then 1 else n * fact (n-1)
```

In the above code segments, the first version gives a stack overflow exception
while the second one works fine. what is the difference between these two?
they seem to function the same but apparently don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OCaml is strict, i.e. all arguments for function `cond` are evaluated when `cond` is called. This includes the call to `fact(n-1)` when `n` is zero, i.e. you will evaluate `fact(-1)` etc. Therefore you have an unterminated recursion and hence a stack overflow.

The second example with the if-then-else statement evaluates only one of the cases, such that the recursion is finite.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the actual answer, a possible way to introduce laziness is to use intermediate functions:

```
let cond (a,b,c) =
  match a with
  | true -> b ()
  | false -> c ()

val cond : bool * (unit -> 'a) * (unit -> 'a) -> 'a = <fun>
```

With this definition, you define `fact` as follows:

```
let rec fact n = 
  cond (n=0, (fun () -> 1), (fun () -> (n * fact (n-1))))

val fact : int -> int = <fun>
```

Each `(fun () -> ...)` expression creates a temporary object, a closure, which captures the variables in its surrounding environment. Closures without parameters are called thunks.
The closures bound to `b` and `c` delay the evaluation of each branch of the test, until you force the execution by calling them.
Closures are not free, in term of resources: unless a compiler finds a way to optimize them, you need to allocate memory each time you evaluate them.